# Prevent tooltip in converting HTML Entities

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```html
<input ng-model="test" placeholder="pre" type="text" title="PROJECT&GT" />
```

The above code for tooltip displays "PROJECT>". But what I need is to display the text as is "PROJECT&GT"

Is there a way to do this? I'm using angular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try something like this:
create angular filter :

```
angular.module('ppvApp.event').filter('escapeHtml', function() {

    var charMap= {
        "&": "&amp;",
        "<": "&lt;",
        ">": "&gt;",
        '"': '&quot;',
        "'": '&#39;',
        "/": '&#x2F;'
    };

    return function(str) {
        return String(str).replace(/[&<>"'\/]/g, function(s) {
            return charMap[s];
        });
    }
});
```

and then use it as:

```
 <input ng-model="test" placeholder="pre" type="text" title="{{'PROJECT&GT' | escapeHtml}}" />
```

Comment: I've combined this technique with the answer above. Thanks :)

Comment: @JenniferFadriquela  Can you mark the solution as useful ? Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the encoded string in the title. You can use online tools such as [this one](http://codebeautify.org/html-encode-string) to do this.

```html
<input ng-model="test" placeholder="pre" type="text" title="PROJECT&amp;GT" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there some sort of utility functions in angular that can automatically convert ampersands to "&amp;"?

Answer (score 1):

One way to go is to separate the `&` from the `GT` (or any other similar entity) with a `&#xfeff;` which is a **Zero Width No-Break Space** (http://www.codetable.net/hex/feff), like this:

```html
<input ng-model="test" placeholder="pre" type="text" title="PROJECT&&#xfeff;GT" />
```