# Prevent Table Cell to Convert HTML Entities

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>&gt;</td>  
    </tr>
     <tr> 
      <td>&&#xfeff;GT</td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have the above code for table cells having html entities. Also, I have a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43179746/prevent-tooltip-in-converting-html-entities/43181649?noredirect=1#comment73694964_43181649) (which is now answered) having the same details but with different scenario.

The goal is to output the string as is, without converting it to HTML Entities. For example the string "Project &GT" will be outputted as is.

Below are 2 solutions I've tried but still does not meet my requirements (these are answers from [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43179746/prevent-tooltip-in-converting-html-entities/43181649?noredirect=1#comment73694964_43181649))

A. First Row - this answer does not correctly display the string. It displays the converted html which is ">". But this solution works on non-table elements like tooltips and spans. Also, if the string has different casing (Project&gT) it outputs the casing from the original string.

B. Second Row - this answer do display the string correctly. It does not output the converted string. But my problem here is if the string has different casing (Project&gT) it will output the case you have encoded on the logic (Project&GT - since this is the one we encoded on the HTML).

Is there a way to have an unconverted string and preserve its casing?

**UPDATE:** Forgot to mention that I am using this with angular.datatable's renderWidth.

```
.renderWith(function(data) {
 return $filter('customFilter')(data)});
```

I've used it together with a customFilter to stop the conversion. In my debugging, the filter returns the correct result but it always has a problem when it renders to table cells . This is why I directly asked the question about  prior to this update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use angular, use ng-bind it's alwais give you the plain text.
Hire is the [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind)

- To get &gt ; use **ng-bind**
- to get > use **ng-bind-html**

Try it.

Comment: I'm still trying to explore this answer. I think it will be better for me to post a new question since this one is now out of the context given my new implementation. Anyways, I will mark this as answer since this makes more sense on a table cell perspective.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
function findNoParse(){
   $('noparse').each(function(){
      if($(this).attr('tagchecked') != 'true'){ //checks if already changed tag
        $(this).text($(this).html()); //makes the html into plaintext
        $(this).attr('tagchecked', 'true'); //says that tag has been checked
      }
   });
 }
```

In HTML

```
<noparse><a href="http://example.com">Link</a></noparse>
```

I have created a fiddle. Please take a look. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GeekyGamer14/6eBxK/)